# Jquery Dynamic div multiple boxes and put into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to create a dynamic div block with fields in but struggling to get this right so that each div blocks  fields are not the same id's when inserting into the database.

Do not know how to go about this... Any help please been struggling for the 2 days now.

Also do not know how to delete the block if i do not need it anymore.
How do i post this dynamically into my database ?

```
<div id="boxwidget" class="box-widget">    
    <div class='form-group hideblockfield'><label><span class='error-title error-fields'></span>Title</label><input type='text' class='form-control' id='title' name='title' placeholder='Title'></div>    

    <div class="form-group hideblockfield">
        <label><span class="error-description error-fields"><?php echo $description_error ?></span>Description</label>
        <textarea rows="3" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea> 

    </div>

    <div id="hideimageroup" class="hideimageroup form-group">
        <label class="hideimagelabel"><span class="error-title error-fields"><?php echo $image_error ?></span>Image</label><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="submit">Open gallery</button>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">
    </div>  

    <div id="hideiconroup" class="hideiconroup form-group">
        <label><span class="error-title error-fields"><?php echo $icon_error ?></span> Icon</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="icon" name="icon" placeholder="Icon">
    </div>                  

    <div class="form-group hideblockfield">
        <label><span class="error-title error-fields"><?php echo $buttontext_error ?></span>Button Text</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buttontext" name="buttontext" placeholder="Button Text">
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group hideblockfield">
        <label><span class="error-btnurl error-fields"><?php echo $buttonurl_error ?></span>Button Url</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buttontext" name="buttontext" placeholder="Button Url">
    </div>  
</div>
```

Add New Box

```
function createnewblock(){

    var $div = $('div[id^="boxwidget1"]:last');

    // And increment that number by 1
    var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;

    // Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 4 to ID "klon4")
    var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'boxwidget1'+num );

    $('#boxarea').append($klon);  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your first line in JS will probably be undefined as there's nothing with an id `boxwidget1` on the page

To remove an element:

```
$('element query').remove()
```

Second, what you're trying to do exactly isn't too clear

**Edit**

The `id` of an element doesn't have any relevance server-side, it's the `name` attribute that gets mapped. Also, the `name` element is only applicable to form elements that are wrapped in a `form` tag, unless you're sending the data via JS. It's difficult to get a clear idea of what going on without more information

Could you perhaps create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: i am confused myself, will this help if i explain better ? I have a div inside of this div is fields, say title and description. when i click on the button to add a new div with the same fields it will append below and then i would like to post this all into my database. how would i go about it ?

Comment: A JSFiddle would be much more helpful as we'd be able to see exactly what you're trying to do. Seeing any server-side code shouldn't really be necessary I don't think

Comment: In the javascript pane, click the cog and you'll have an option for `framework`. There you can select the version of JQuery that you're using

Comment: Also, within that menu, set the `load-type` to `no-wrap in body`

Comment: cool fixed it :) what do i do now? delete a div and post the dynamic fields to the db

Comment: First off, I wouldn't use a `div`. Instead, use a `form`. Then, you don't have to worry about managing ids or anything like that and you get the bonus of it automatically setting the server-side target through the `action` attribute. If you really want to from there, you can submit the form through javascript to your PHP action that will insert into the database